# How to deploy angular 4 apps on app engine without uploading 220MB of node_modules

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to deploy my angular 4 apps on google cloud app engine and I thing.

If i  have 220mb of data in node_modules I want to deploy only the dist folder, not other data . in the past I have separate folder and when I build the app with `ng build --prod` I copy the **dist** folder that is MAX 10mb and I move the folder into the folder where I have the express and then I deploy the app in the google cloud there is any way that I can tell the Google cloud what data I want to upload on cloud. 
or there is something like .gitignore that ignores the node_modules folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at using `skip_files` in your `app.yaml`

```
skip_files:
- node_modules/
```

More here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#Python_app_yaml_Skipping_files

Comment: Thnx Brother MarkM

Comment: can I ask you if I need all times to set skip_files node_modules or is not necessary